# Collecting & filtering a large amount of data

Tags: java, database

I have little JAVA coding experience (some classes at university) but none in the area of data collecting.

I want to monitor all the messages send on a CAN bus & store these temporarily to filter them afterwords so I can isolate some specific messages.

This means I have to store a maximum of 17543 messages of 1 byte every second. I would like to store  - at least - a couple of tens of seconds.

What the best way to do this?

Can I just store all of these in an array? 
Would it be better to use a database (such as Hibernate)?

I know this is rather open-ended but I would like to get an idea of what's possible and what's the best direction to handle this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you get (at most) 17,543 messages per second, each of which is only 1 byte, and you'll want to store a couple of tens of seconds?

That's not a lot of data, and you can easily store that in an array in memory. Suppose you want to store the messages of 1 minute, that would be 17,543 x 60 seconds = less than 1 MB of data. That's peanuts on modern computers. A database would be overkill.

Comment: Thank you very much. What would be a limit to this memory?

Comment: Your PC probably has a few GB (a few thousand MB) memory. That's thousands of times more than what you'd need for this.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is not a database. It's an ORM.

```
20 seconds = 20 * 17543 bytes 
           = 350860 bytes
           = 350 KB 
           = nothing.
```

Storing everything in memory wouldn't be a problem for such a small amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

> I have to store a maximum of 17543 messages of 1 byte every second. I would like to store - at least - a couple of tens of seconds.

It might make sense to store the messages in a [circular buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_buffer). This can be easily implemented using an array.

30 seconds worth of data will require ~500KB of storage.